# In GIT, what is the best way for a project to mix old and new versions of sub-components?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose a project is to use an old frozen version of Component1 (say revision Rev1) but the current (master) version of all other files. Component1 is a directory in the same repository.

GIT's "whole fileset view" seems to be awkward in this case. In CVS, one could simply put a sticky tag on Component1 to freeze those files at Rev1, or even branch there, while all other files would stay on the master branch.

The repository is used for other projects that want the latest Component1 so we can't simply roll back the updates to Component1.

One possibility is to create a branch at Rev1, but then one must constantly be merging in updates to all other files from master. Moreover, I have to be very careful on those merges to not accidentally merge any updates to Component1, which is easy to do in GIT because commits are by default automatic after a merge.

Mapping Component1 in as a submodule would provide more control but in this case all files are sharing a common repository.

"git checkout <rev> -- Component1" lets me pick a specific version of a component, but I can't commit that to master, or merge a branch into master that does such a revision selection, or else it will be exposed to all other projects.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the only sensible solution from git's point of view is using submodules. Those exist pretty much for the reason of providing functionality like you described. What exactly is preventing you from using submodules?

Comment: Like @user1338062 said, I think submodules is what you are looking for. Other option is a package manager.